# Quiero crear dos redes LAN independientes (Oficina y Producción)

Tags: redes

Para mejorar la seguridad de mi red, quiero separar totalmente la red LAN de oficina y la red LAN de producción y que producción solo pueda acceder a ciertos servidores específicos.

¿Cuál es la mejor opción para que producción no vea oficinas y únicamente vea uno o dos servidores?

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque  no es sobre programación

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tiene dos opciones.

1) Clásica: definir dos redes distintas y que su estructura (cableado) nunca se unan en un mismo switchs. Solo en el router de conexión de ambas, si lo desea, o para la conexión a internet

2) Mediante VLAN: Aquí no importa el cableado. A cada red se la define una VLAN. Para esto necesita switchs que soporte la norma 802.1Q.

Dicha norma estable que cada paquete ira etiquetado mediante un identificador de VLAN.

Por lo tanto para cada red usted debe definir un ID.

Oficina = 192.168.10.0/24, VLAN ID = 5

Produccion = 192.168.20.0/24 VLAN ID = 15

Cada cliente se debe conectar a un puerto de un switch determinado que estará etiquetado por el respectivo ID de la VLAN.

En extremo puede tener un router para que defina si enruta o no paquetes hacia cada red y como es el ruteo hacia internet.

Para su problema puede definir regla de routeo para acceder a sus servidores. O crear una VLAN para sus servidores, de tal forma que la VLAN de Oficina nunca se vea con Produción pero ambas vean la VLAN de los Servidores.

Puede ver el concepto en la Wikipedia: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/VLAN

Comment: por favor no respondas a preguntas que no son basadas en la temática del sitio, ayuda a mantener la calidad del mismo; por otro lado la pregunta se basa en opiniones y por lo mismo terminará cerrada

Comment: Usted tiene razón. Stackoverflow es solo para programación.
Disculpas, gracias. Lo tendré en cuenta.